# DLL Injection fails with code 127

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, code-injection

I am trying to do some dll injection. I think I tried everything I could but cound not solve the problem unfortunately. I always get ERROR CODE 127 which means ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND. I am using Windows 7 64 bit.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>

using namespace std;

char FileToInject[] = "theDll.dll";
char ProcessName[] = "calc.exe";

typedef HINSTANCE (*fpLoadLibrary)(char*);

bool InjectDLL(DWORD processId);

int main() {
    DWORD processId = NULL;

    PROCESSENTRY32 pre32 = {sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32)};
    HANDLE hProcSnap;
    cout << "BEFORECreateToolhelo32Snapshot:" << GetLastError() <<endl;
    while(!processId) {

            system("CLS");
            cout << "Searching..." << endl;
            hProcSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
            cout << "CreateToolhelo32Snapshot:" << GetLastError() <<endl;

            if(Process32First(hProcSnap, &pre32)) {

                    do {

                        if(!(strcmp(pre32.szExeFile, ProcessName))) {

                           processId = pre32.th32ProcessID;
                           break;

                        }

                    }
                    while(Process32Next(hProcSnap, &pre32));
            }
            Sleep(1000);
    }
    cout << GetLastError() <<endl;
    while(!InjectDLL(processId)) {
        cout << "DLL Injection failed" << endl;
        Sleep(1000);
    }

    cout << "DLL Injected successfully" << endl;
    getchar();
    CloseHandle(hProcSnap);

    return 0;
}

bool InjectDLL(DWORD processId) {

    HANDLE hProc;
    LPVOID paramAddr;
    cout << "START:" << GetLastError() <<endl;
    HINSTANCE hDll = LoadLibrary("KERNEL32");
    cout << "LoadLibrary:" << GetLastError() <<endl;

    fpLoadLibrary LoadLibraryAddr = (fpLoadLibrary)GetProcAddress(hDll, "LibraryLoadA");
    cout << "LoadLibraryArr:" << GetLastError() <<endl;
    hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, processId);
    cout << "OpenProcess:" << GetLastError() <<endl;
    char DllPath[250] = "C:\\Hacks\test.dll";

    paramAddr = VirtualAllocEx(hProc, 0, strlen(DllPath) + 1, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    cout << "VirtualAlloxEx:" <<GetLastError() <<endl;
    bool MemoryWritten = WriteProcessMemory(hProc, paramAddr, DllPath, strlen(DllPath) + 1, NULL);
    cout << "WriteProcessMemory:" << GetLastError() <<endl;
    CreateRemoteThread(hProc, 0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)LoadLibraryAddr, paramAddr, 0, 0);
    cout << "CreateRemoteThread:" <<GetLastError() <<endl;
    CloseHandle(hProc);
    return MemoryWritten;
}
```

The output is the following:

```
Searching...
CreateToolhelp32Snapshot: 18 ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES
LoadLibrary:18 ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES
LoadLibraryArr:127 ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND
OpenProcess:127 ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND
VirtualAlloxEx:127 ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND
WriteProcessMemory:127 ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND
CreateRemoteThread:5 ACCESS DENIED
DLL Injected successfully
```

The program finds the calc.exe as a process with no problem, but after that something goes wrong. Could someone please help me with this?

Thank you,

Tamas

Comment: On which line is the error? Did you check with dependency walker to see the exact name of the exported procedure?

Comment: @thefiloe: Please only add a comment to the question if it adds any value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one problem:

```
char DllPath[250] = "C:\\Hacks\test.dll";
```

The last backslash is not escaped. Change to:

```
char DllPath[250] = "C:\\Hacks\\test.dll";
```

The function is called `LoadLibraryA()`, not `LibraryLoadA()`:

```
fpLoadLibrary LoadLibraryAddr =
    (fpLoadLibrary)GetProcAddress(hDll, "LibraryLoadA");
```

A few other suggestions:

- Only check `GetLastError()` if the previous WINAPI function failed.
- Only continue processing if the previous WINAPI code (or other code) succeeded.

Comment: Thanks hmjd this solved my problem. One more thing. I sent it to my friend and he got the same output as me but it does not work for him. He's on a Windows 7 64 bit too. How could this happen? He built the solution on his computer with no problem.

Comment: Only advice I can give is ensure everything is identical. What do you mean by _same output_? If you give him your binaries does it work?

Comment: The only difference I think is I am using Visual C++ Express 2010 and he is using the latest VS. Building shows no error. Output shows no error. However, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

In

```
fpLoadLibrary LoadLibraryAddr = (fpLoadLibrary)GetProcAddress(hDll, "LibraryLoadA");
```

you should rather resolve the string `LoadLibraryA`. The

```
OpenProcess:127 ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND
VirtualAlloxEx:127 ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND (<-- sic)
WriteProcessMemory:127 ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND
```

errors are caused because you're using `GetLastError` even though these functions maybe didn't even fail. So before calling `GetLastError`, make sure that these functions yield an error return value (NULL or the like).